# How efficient of a program that read from stdin than a file?

Tags: c, performance, pipe, stdin, fopen

Actually this is not particular to C, but assume using C first, if I have a program that read from `stdin`, and a program read from a file using `fopen`, how to compare their efficiency in processing file?

What would be the overheads on both cases?

Comment: You could test it, but I imagine there won't be much/any meaningful difference. The bottle neck will be hard drive seek time on a traditional hard drive, and access time on an SSD.  These will vary enough that you might not even get an accurate difference in a test if the difference is smaller than variance in seek.  `stdin` may have slightly more overhead, as it is meant for user entry, but if you are piping a file into to, I doubt it is enough to make a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to compare reading from a file that's received as `stdin` (e.g. `./prog < file`) versus opened within the program via `fopen`, there should be no difference in efficiency whatsoever.

If you mean to compare reading from a pipe or terminal or other non-regular-file received as `stdin` versus opening  regular file with `fopen`, you're comparing apples and oranges and I don't think the question makes sense without further details.